# Create `NULL` variable in tibble list column

Tags: r, null, tidyverse, tibble

I want to create combinations of a list with 3 named elements i.e. `B`, `m`, `replace`. For example `list(B = 50, m = 100, replace = FALSE)` would be one such instance of a list. I want to store these combinations as a list column in a `tibble`, along with the combination of grid values of `B`, `m`, `replace` as separate columns that are used to construct the individual `list` values.

To currently build such lists, I create a sequence grid for individual values `B`, `m`, `replace`, and then just cross join and mutate. A reprex is shown as below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create individual sequences of grid values to cross join
B <- seq(from = 50, to = 250, by = 50)
m <- seq(from = 100, to = 300, by = 100)

# Uncommenting this line - causes issues
# m <- c(NA, m)

# Don't call it replace, so function replace function is not overidden
replc <- c(TRUE, FALSE)

# Inspect the individual grid values
B
#> [1]  50 100 150 200 250
m
#> [1] 100 200 300
replc
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE

# TODO: Need to construct just NULL value
out_crossing <- tidyr::crossing(B, m, replc) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(.data = ., B, m) %>% 
    dplyr::rename("replace" = replc) %>% 
    dplyr::rowwise(data = .) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(boot_emp = list(tibble::lst("B" = B, 
                                              "m" = ifelse(!is.na(m), m, NULL), 
                                              "replace" = replace)))

# Seems to work, but would be nice to have 
head(out_crossing, 3)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       B     m replace boot_emp        
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   <list>          
#> 1    50   100 FALSE   <named list [3]>
#> 2    50   100 TRUE    <named list [3]>
#> 3    50   200 FALSE   <named list [3]>

# Check an individual element is a list with 3 elements
out_crossing[1, 4]$boot_emp
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$B
#> [1] 50
#> 
#> [[1]]$m
#> [1] 100
#> 
#> [[1]]$replace
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This works. Though there is a small twist. For the value of `m` I would like the list to contain `NULL` values i.e. would like `list(B = 50, m = NULL, replace = FALSE)` as one of the outputs. Unfortunately you can't add `NULL` values to a vector. So as a hack, I tried to add
`NA` values i.e. by uncommenting the line `# m <- c(NA, m)` in the reprex above, and then adjusting the `NA` value to a `NULL` when in the `mutate` line `"m" = ifelse(!is.na(m), m, NULL)` in the final list. This gave an `error`:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `boot_emp`.
x replacement has length zero
ℹ Input `boot_emp` is `list(tibble::lst(B = B, m = ifelse(!is.na(m), m, NULL), replace = replace))`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 7.
```

Could anyone please show how to get this working, if possible?

Comment: `NULL` will be removed in a `vector`.  May be you need `NA`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Yes, `NULL` will be removed. So as mentioned I tried uncommenting `m <- c(NA, m)` and running the above. Which gave the error

Comment: The `ifelse` step should be replace with `NA`

Comment: So I'm trying to specifically have `NULL` values in the final list i.e. I seek `list(B = 50, m = NULL, replace = FALSE)` for example. In the code I tried to replace the `NA` values for `m` to a `NULL` value using `"m" = ifelse(!is.na(m), m, NULL)` in the `mutate. Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the `ifelse` step where each argument should have the same `length`, but

```
length(NULL)
#[1] 0
```

So, we may need to change the condition to have `NA` as 'no' value instead of `NULL` in `ifelse`

If we need `NULL` values, it is not possible in a `vector`, but can be wrapped in a `list` i.e.

```
out_crossing <- tidyr::crossing(B, m, replc) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(.data = ., B, m) %>% 
    dplyr::rename("replace" = replc) %>% 
    dplyr::rowwise(data = .) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(boot_emp = list(tibble::lst("B" = B, 
                              "m" = ifelse(!is.na(m), m, list(NULL)), 
                                              "replace" = replace)))
```

Then, we remove the `list` wrapping

```
out_crossing$boot_emp <- purrr::map(out_crossing$boot_emp, 
    ~ purrr::map(.x, ~ if(is.list(.x) && is.null(.x[[1]])) NULL else .x ))
```

-output

```
out_crossing$boot_emp[40]
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$B
#[1] 250

#[[1]]$m
#NULL

#[[1]]$replace
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or if there is only a single element, just do `if/else`

```
out_crossing <- tidyr::crossing(B, m, replc) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(.data = ., B, m) %>% 
    dplyr::rename("replace" = replc) %>% 
    dplyr::rowwise(data = .) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(boot_emp = list(tibble::lst("B" = B, 
                              "m" = if(!is.na(m)) m else NULL, 
                                              "replace" = replace)))
              
              
out_crossing$boot_emp[40]
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$B
#[1] 250

#[[1]]$m
#NULL

#[[1]]$replace
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need `NULL` values. This affects other list validation downstream which filters out `NULL` values specifically.

Comment: @user4687531 can you check the updated post

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful post. This does give the required style of output. I believe there is a more efficient way to do this using `switch`, which I just found by experimenting. But I like having alternative ways to solve problems, like your suggestion

Comment: Ideally yes, I wanted to use `ifelse`, but with a relatively simple change ideally, rather than a complicated post processing `map` statement. I like your solution, but I have just posted an alternative below. If you are aware of alternatives to `ifelse` prior to solving, I'd have been glad to learn them. Thanks for taking time on this.

Comment: @user4687531 you can simply use `if/else` here as the length is 1 (updated) and it doesn't have that constraint as in `ifelse`

Comment: ah, that is clever. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting, and reading [this helpful thread](http://r-addict.com/2017/02/21/switch-ifelse.html#:%7E:text=This%20function%20is%20a%20simple,a%20result%20of%20this%20evaluation.), I realized that there is a way to do this, but by using a `switch` statement, instead of an `ifelse` statement. The full `reprex` is given below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create individual sequences of grid values to cross join
B <- seq(from = 50, to = 250, by = 50)
m <- seq(from = 100, to = 300, by = 100)

# Allow NULL values for m. However, vectors can't take NULL values so we
# set add NA values instead. We will coerce these to NULL values at the time
# the list is constructed
m <- c(NA, m)

# Don't call it replace, so function replace function is not overidden
replc <- c(TRUE, FALSE)

# Inspect the individual grid values
B
#> [1]  50 100 150 200 250
m
#> [1]  NA 100 200 300
replc
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE

# TODO: Need to construct just NULL value
out_crossing <- tidyr::crossing(B, m, replc) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(.data = ., B, m) %>% 
    dplyr::rename("replace" = replc) %>% 
    dplyr::rowwise(data = .) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(boot_emp = list(tibble::lst("B" = B, 
                                              "m" = switch(!is.na(m), m, NULL),
                                              # "m" = ifelse(!is.na(m), m, NULL), 
                                              "replace" = replace)))

# Seems to work, but would be nice to have 
head(out_crossing, 3)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       B     m replace boot_emp        
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   <list>          
#> 1    50   100 FALSE   <named list [3]>
#> 2    50   100 TRUE    <named list [3]>
#> 3    50   200 FALSE   <named list [3]>
# out_crossing %>% dplyr::glimpse()
# out_crossing %>% View()

# Check an individual element is a list with 3 elements
out_crossing[8, 4]$boot_emp
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$B
#> [1] 50
#> 
#> [[1]]$m
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[1]]$replace
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Hope this helps others. I'd like to see other ways to solve this, that may have advantages over this approach. So please keep adding to this thread so myself and others can learn.